# How to extract date from String column using regex in Spark

Tags: regex, scala, apache-spark

I have a dataframe which consist of filename, email and other details. Need to get the dates out of it from one of the column file name.

Ex: **File name**: Test_**04_21_2019**_34600.csv

**Need to extract the date**: 04_21_2019

**Dataframe**

```
val df1 = Seq(
  ("Test_04_21_2018_1200.csv", "abc@gmail.com",200),
  ("home/server2_04_15_2020_34610.csv", "abc1@gmail.com", 300),
  ("/server1/Test3_01_2_2019_54680.csv", "abc2@gmail.com",800))
.toDF("file_name", "email", "points")
```

**Output To be**

```
date         email           points
04_21_2018   abc@gmail.com   200
04_15_2020   abc1@gmail.com  300
01_2_2019    abc2@gmail.com  800
```

Can we use regex on spark dataframe to achieve this or any other way to achieve this. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [regexp_extract](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#regexp_extract-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-int-) function to extract the date as below

```
val resultDF = df1.withColumn("date", 
  regexp_extract($"file_name", "\\d{1,2}_\\d{1,2}_\\d{4}", 0)
)
```

Output:

```
+--------------------+--------------+------+----------+
|           file_name|         email|points|      date|
+--------------------+--------------+------+----------+
|Test_04_21_2018_1...| abc@gmail.com|   200|04_21_2018|
|home/server2_04_1...|abc1@gmail.com|   300|04_15_2020|
|/server1/Test3_01...|abc2@gmail.com|   800| 01_2_2019|
+--------------------+--------------+------+----------+
```